# how to manage project code repository

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

I have few queries on how to maintain code versions for a web application developing project.

we are five people working from different home locations for a payment web application project. I want to know how to maintain code repository for that. Since we are working from different location each one will work at different timings ,because of that i want to make sure everyone is having the latest code in there machine before starting the work.

Any suggestion would be helpful to start. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up a project code repository on a system that everyone can access.  That means, somewhere on the Internet.

Git repositories are available on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

Subversion repositories are available on [SvnRepository](http://svnrepository.com/).

I don't know Git, but with Subversion, when a developer performs a Subversion update, all of the changes committed by others are downloaded to the developer's working copy.

When a developer performs a Subversion commit, his or her changes are committed to Subversion.  You'll want to come up with a standardized commit message format to make the Subversion logs easier for everyone to read.

Your developers have to get in the habit of updating first, and committing last.

Someone will have to create and maintain a build process that takes the code from Subversion and makes an executable system.

Comment: Thanks.Is it open source?